# Sonicwall Routing Subnets

Tags: networking, routing, subnet, sonicwall

I have a Sonicwall TZ105W that has a Synology NAS (10.0.0.8) on the LAN zone (10.0.2.0/24). The NAS provides a VPN service that is delegated a 10.0.2.0/24 network. How can I set up routing on the Sonicwall so that LAN devices on the 10.0.0.0/24 network can communicate with the VPN network 10.0.2.0/24? I tried setting up a route on the Sonicwall, but the devices on the LAN don't want to follow it. Devices on the 10.0.2.0/24 can connect to the 10.0.0.0/24 network just fine.

_______________                          __________________
|     WAN     |                          |VPN 10.0.2.0/24 |
|_____________|                          |________________|
      |                                          |
______x1________                         ________|_________
|  SONICWALL   |                         |  NAS (10.0.0.8)|
|______________|-x0-(LAN 10.0.0.0/24)--->|________________|

Answer (score 0):

Got it, long story short, when applying routes, restart the Sonicwall!